# Deploying django application on apache server

Tags: python, django, apache

I m trying to Deploy my django application on apache server (Xampp)

Present Versions :-

```
Python 3.7.3
Xampp :- 3.2.4
Apache :- 2.4
windows 10
```

Note:- i am using virtual environment

Was searching how to do that and encountered this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6-yJpPEpoE&t=193s)

However, After making the changes which are same as django Documentation. my apache server is not running

Its throwing the error

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.      This may be due to a blocked
>   port, missing dependencies,       improper privileges, a crash, or a
>   shutdown by another method.   Press the Logs button to view error logs
>   and check     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues     If you need more
>   help, copy and post this      entire log window on the forums

i did changed my port in **httpd.conf** to some other which was not used by another application, I am not able to figure out what is the issue.

Added to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/xxxx/appdata/local/programs/python/python37-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
WSGIScriptAlias / "K:/Work/DevNet/first_project/first_project/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32"
WSGIPythonPath "K:/Work/Net/first_project"


<Directory "K:/Work/Net/first_project">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Also in httpd.conf if i am commenting the added lines then the apache works fine, but when i uncomment those lines apache doesn't works. :-(

Thanku those willing to help. :-)

Windows Event Viewer logs :-

```
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:05.852622 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:05.928109 2019] [core:warn] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.027802 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.049409 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s PHP/7.1.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.049409 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: May 29 2019 14:38:49
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.049409 2019] [core:notice] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.072102 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9612:tid 560] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12636
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.769853 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 12636:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.959523 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 12636:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Aug 10 19:00:06.981305 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12636:tid 524] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst there are 4 requirements you should comply with.

As far as I can see, you fail to comply with the first rule, as you have Apache Win64 version `Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)` but you are using a 32 bit python version and mod_wsgi `python37-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd`

Also, I noticed you say that you are using virtual environment. Make sure that your `wsgi.py` loads the virtual environment first. My file starts like that:

```py
python_home='/path/to/the/djangoproject/venv'
activate_this=python_home+'/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
        exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Also, I recommend configuring mod_wsgi to run in Daemon Mode, by specifying the WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup directives in your VirtualHost file.

Answer (score 0):

In the logs (in the configured step), it should display the WSGI module version too.
But your log doesn't say anything about WSGI - so I suspect that you didn't do the WSGI setup correctly.
I have posted an example log from my apache (of course it's different OS, but it should be similar).

```
[Fri Aug 02 13:51:39.962856 2019] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.6.7 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: from cmd when i m running **pip install mod_wsgi** it shows the following `Requirement already satisfied: mod_wsgi in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\py
on37-32\lib\site-packages (4.6.7+ap24vc15)`

Comment: **pip install mod_wsgi** will install WSGI into Python2 (not python3). Please use `pip3 install mod_wsgi` to install wsgi into python3. This is the step we follow for the setup in linux/mac. I guess, it should be same for windows too.

Comment: @P K `pip3 install mod_wsgi` also says requirement satisfied

Comment: In the httpd.conf you have **<Directory "K:/Work/Net/first_project">** (OR) **<Directory "K:/Work/Net/first_project/first_project">**?

Comment: my wsgi.py file of project is stored in  **K:/Work/Net/first_project/first_project**. i have my project in **K:/Work/Net/first_project (file containing the manage.py)/ first_project(file containing setings.py, wsgi.py)**

Comment: No. You didn't understand my question. Can you try the below configuration in your httpd.conf
````<Directory "K:/Work/Net/first_project/first_project">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>````
Because the wsgi.py will not be available in the root folder of your project.

Comment: ohkay.! got your Question. i did configure my httpd.conf in the way you have written. Also after doing this i even restarted my pc (just to be sure). but no luck. and thnku for you efforts. :-)